# Tv error in main menu of games

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics, games, steam

i started to get literally TV error in a game (V rising) after installing fresh ubuntu (22.04 LTS) to my laptop. Here is the ss of error and my things:

[tv error,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnjSa.jpg)
[my specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ST31.png)
[and the logs when i start the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlizM.png)

tell me if you need anything else, im new to ubuntu and english, sorry in advance.

Comment: This looks to be an issue with the game. They most likely use a background image which is the TV error screen. It might be best to contact the devs or any support communities if such are available. It does not look like a driver issue or anything like that at all to me.

Comment: I had no problem before the fresh install, it was working perfectly. Also i don't have any problem in game its just the main menu and start animation.

Comment: It might have some error loading the main menu image/video animation and when it fails to load it, it could be displaying that as a fall-back. But certainly this doesn't look like an OS issue to me. If it's a Steam game, try right-click game in library -> properties -> installed files -> verify integrity. This will detect any broken files and re-download.

Comment: I verified integrity of the game files but it didn't fix. And I'm downloading another game to see if I get any errors there.

Comment: You can try [Steam Support - V Rising](https://help.steampowered.com/en/wizard/HelpWithGame/?appid=1604030) or contact them via social media (Twitter, Discord, etc. links available on their website https://playvrising.com/)

Comment: Yep I'll try to contact them later on after seeing if it's only to this game or not. But I still don't get it. How is the "TV Error" happening? It should be fine as before like 2-3 days ago. Maybe I'm missing some important files? If so, do you know how to check it?